# Pasar parámetros desde Ajax a un controlador en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, base-de-datos, codeigniter

Tengo este script en del Ajax donde capturo los valores de entrada

```
function registrarUsuario() {
    var nombre = $("#nombres").val(); 
    var ape = $("#apellidos").val();
    var id = $("#identificacion").val();
    var pass =$("#contra").val();
   
    alert(nombre+ape+id+pass);
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/PruebaA/UsuarioController/registrarUsuario",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data:{
            "nombres": nombre,
                "apellidos": ape,
                "identificacion":id, 
                "contra": pass
        },
               
        success: function (data) { 
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            $("#loader").hide();
        }
        
    });
}
```

Pero al recibir a data en el controlador, éste no recibe los parámetros e ingresa valores vacíos en la base de datos.

```
public function registrarUsuario(){
    $nombres =  $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('nombres'));
    $apellidos =  $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('apellidos'));
    $identificacion =  $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('identificacion'));
    $contra =  $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('contra'));

    $result = $this->Usuario_model->insertar($nombres, $apellidos, $identificacion, $contra);
}
```

Comment: Entonces todos los `$this->input->post()` estan vacios?

Answer (score 0):

Intentar averiguar el error que te esta mostrando por consola el error y el success con esto:

```
success: function (data) { 
  alert(data);
},
error: function (response) {
  console.log(response.responseText);
}
```

puede que sea un error de tu URL porque por lo que veo tu llamada ajax esta bien

Comment: no me aparece error, solamente inserta valores vacios a la base de datos

Comment: cuando hace el alert(nombre+api......) te muestra los datos ingresados de los label?

Comment: si, el alert se activa y muestra los datos, cuando se activa la funcion OnClick del boton

Comment: Tambien podrias intentar hacer un ECHO sin utilizar el filtrado para comprobar si realmente estan llegando o si es un problema del filtrado. con ECHO JSON_ENCODE ($_POST["nombres"]) deberia funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que esten llegado los datos por POST a tu metodo

```
public function registrarUsuario(){ print_r($_POST); }
```